# submit an R package with CTAN dependencies to CRAN

Tags: r, latex, packaging, cran, external-dependencies

I am currently working on an R package that is going to be submitted CRAN within a few weeks. The package needs some latex packages to run. Those latex packages are available on CTAN and injected in the preamble of RMarkdown documents via `rmarkdown::latex_dependency()`.

This is the concept of my [actual knit_print method](https://github.com/R-package/styledTables/blob/5d38b6b6ef7bcdabc30e98e3a60a66c3c145aa51/R/knit_print.R#L35-L45).

```r
#' @export
knit_print.my_class <- function(obj, ...) {
  knitr::raw_latex(
    to_latex(obj), 
    meta = list(
      rmakrdown::latex_dependency(
        "ragged2e"
      )
    )
  )
}
```

---

My question is how those dependencies can be specified in a way such that CRAN is going to accept this submission. As far as I can tell, there are four options

1. submit the package as-is and add installation instructions via the documentation and the `SystemRequirements` field of the DESCRIPTION file.
2. include all necessary latex packages in my R package and somehow make them available to the client's latex compiler
3. add a dependency to [tinytex](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex) which can install CTAN packages automatically
4. Throw an error during installation if the dependencies are not met

So far, I used option (1).

---

My configuration for travis (ubuntu 14.04) is

```
apt install texlive-latex-extra
tlmgr install standalone
```

For appveyor (Windows Server 2012 R2 x64), I unpack `miktex-portable.exe` and add it to the PATH. Then I get the following packages.

```
mpm --install=standalone
mpm --install=ms
mpm --install=pbox
mpm --install=xcolor
mpm --install=colortbl
mpm --install=mptopdf
```

---

What I found out so far

- using google to search for external dependencies and CRAN sumbissions only yielded information about C and C++ dependencies, which didn't help my cause.
- Looking at some source code revealed that `rticles` include certain `.sty` files directly in `inst/` which leads me to believe, that (2) is the correct answer. However, `rticles` defines custom output formats and those don't have to "install" the latex packages since the `.sty` files are copied to the render directory as part of a template.
- [magick](https://github.com/ropensci/magick) uses a config file that prevents the installation in case (system) dependencies are not met. It also throws an informative error message that instructs the client how the dependencies can be met.
- the tinytex package did not run any compile tests on CRAN when it was submitted. I also can't make tinytex it work on appveyor

Answer (score 2):

I am reasonably familiar with the [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) and there is generally no provision for *external dependencies* off CRAN etc.

That said I stretched CRAN a little to by downloading pre-built libraries off GitHub as needed.  You could model your package after that.

But what I really think you should do is to ... prepare your pdf vignette locally and then have the R package 'inject' it as is.  How to do that is explained eg in [this post by Mark](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2019/01/11/add-a-static-pdf-vignette-to-an-r-package/) and I just converted my [RcppAnnoy](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy) package to do just that. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: Thank you very much. The tex dependencies are not only required for the vignettes but also for the use of most package functions. I just edited my question to make this more clear. If the test environments of the CRAN maintainers are not able to resolve these dependencies I'd have to use `\dontrun{}` to prevent examples and unit tests from invoking the tex compiler. Could you please provide a github permalink that demonstrates the "stretching" of CRAN?